# Force variable in tuple to have same type as generic type of other variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Imagine the following code:

```
interface SomeClass<T> {
  someFnc(value: T): boolean;
}

const a: SomeClass<string>;

const b: MissingType = [a, c];
```

I want to achieve that c has to be a string, because the generic type input of SomeClass is a string. Can somebody tell me how MissingType has to be defined?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a new type ?

```
type MyTuple<T> = [SomeClass<T>, T];
const b: MyTuple<string> = [a, c];
```

Comment: Now I recognize that my question was not perfectly worded. Sorry for this :( I will use this tuples in an array: `const somVar = [[a, c], ...]`. Of course I could create an own type and do something like `[[a, c] as MyTuple<string>, ...], but my hope was that I can omit this extra casting and can directly derive type of c.